# UIButton Custom Image in AlertViews

Tags: iphone

Im planning to create an Alert view with three buttons, my problem is I want to make the UIButton to custom and change its image.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom view with the buttons you want, then display it using `presentModalController:animated:`.

You may find this article helpful for implementing your own view that looks like an alert view: http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/

Comment: What do you mean modally? As in it's only the active dialog?